# Laravel Carbon diffForHumans convert to Days

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have domains table in table ı have expired_at columns.

I want to show remaining days but if domains expired 30 days ago its saying just 30 or if will expire after 30 days its showing 30

how ı can do like this ;

```
55 days
-55 days
```

I used 'parts' = 1,2,3,4,5,5

```
{{  \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($domain->expired_at))->diffForHumans()}}
```

Comment: You don’t want `diffForHumans`, but simply `diffInDays` …?

Comment: yes your right ben when i used diffindays if its expired ı want to  say -30 or 30 days ago expired but now its same if expired 30 or after 30

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Please edit your question to include a proper example of what you are doing. (And please go check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: All `diff*` methods in Carbon would require you to pass another Carbon instance as their argument. So I think your code example makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a param to the diffInDays function :

```php
 \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($domain->expired_at))->diffInDays(now(), false)
```

Adding the `false` param allow to bypass the absolute value

source : https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Comment: Hello Mathieu I did that solution its done  but when I list my domain if domain has expired 30 days ago its write like 30 days ago and if domains have 60 days to expire its write like -60 days can we turn that

Comment: domain1.com | 30 days | expired ----- domain2.com | -30 days | Active

Comment: You should read the documentation for DiffForHumans :https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff You shoudl find a modifier suitable for you :)